# CSS divs lookng like a windows folder icon

Tags: css, html

how can I get a layout like this with css?

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _
|                        \
|   People                \     link1           link2
|                          \
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ _
|                                                               |
|                content                                        |
|                                                               |
|_ _ _ __ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Sorry my question should have been specific.. I don't know how to get that slant kind of look.. I did everything else with tables.. I guess I need to know how to get the first <td> right border to look like a slant line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only challenge here is People.  You can do it by putting this in a class called like "people_slanted" or something like that:

```
border-bottom: 100px solid red;
border-left: 0 solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 150px;
```

That code above i stole/modified from: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/
(Be sure to check for browser compatibility)

You mentioned you are using a table in your follow up comment.  One easy way might be to create a basic class for this slant then wrap up your table's top left cell (the one that's supposed to be slanted) in a div/span with the class "people_slanted" or whatever you name it.

Comment: One other thing... You might want to look @ something like Blueprint CSS.  It makes working with grid layouts pretty easy which might be helpful because this looks like a grid to me... especially if you had subfolders and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Simple css

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 30% 0, 34% 10%, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
```

This works by starting at 0,0 which is the top left then working each point clockwise.  You can use px instead of %.

Answer (score 0):

Folder style for bootstrap card.

**CSS**

```
.class {
    background-color: yellow; 
    color: #222;
    clip-path: polygon(0 23%, 0 7%, 4% 0, 29% 0, 32% 7%, 60% 7%, 98% 7%, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 15% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 85%);
}
```